# Unable to Retrieve Lot of Data with ajax

Tags: jquery, mysql, asp.net, ajax

```
       $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "ajaxcode.aspx/article",
               data: "{'str' : '" + id + "'}",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               success: function (data) {...        }
                });
```

CS code

```
     [WebMethod]
      public static List<ARTICLE> article(string str)
      {
       IEnumerable<ARTICLE> item;
       DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
       item = db.ARTICLEs.Where(o => o.STATUS == "1" && o.CAT_id ==  
       int.Parse(str)).ToList().Take(7);
       List<ARTICLE> list = new List<ARTICLE>();
       if (item.Any())
       {
           foreach (var item1 in item)
           {
               list.Add(item1);
           }
             }
        return list;
       }
```

Hi everyone, 
I'm getting the record from database using ajax in asp.net. Code was working fine but as I loaded lot of data in the table ajax code unable to fetch that record.
Is there any limit in ajax to get data from database? 
Here is my code:

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Do you get a timeout? Empty result? What is the response?

Comment: Here is the error.

Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj, StringBuilder output, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)

Comment: Issue solved. Thank for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your LINQ code is only requesting 7 records total.

".Take(7);"

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes it is requesting 7 records total and I have more than 7 records. It is also not working without using "Take(7)".